# Excel Formula - Compare two tables (If match is found in name, calculate difference in charges.)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula, lookup

I am trying to figure out a formula to find and calculate the difference in charges from two tables which has matching facility names. If facility name does not have a match then leave blank or if NA in calculation cell.

[image: EXCEL tables comparison]

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: `VLOOKUP()`? What have you tried? Questions like this are asked probably once a week, if not more often, here on SO. Have you searched for anything?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot I'm assuming the first row after the header is on row 7. You can try to paste this to cell J7:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(RIGHT(F7,2)," - ", G7),B:D,2,FALSE)-H7,"")
```

What it does is using vlookup function to get the data from the other table. But since they don't have the common value, I use `CONCATENATE(RIGHT(F7,2)," - ", G7)` to generate common value assuming column B has a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are trying to do:

[image]

This is the formula to enter from `cell J6` and you can drag it to `K6` as well:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$6:C$12,MATCH("*"&$G6&"*",$B$6:$B$12,0))-H6,"")
```

Basically, the trick is to use wildcard `*` to perform this search.  Try and let me know if this is what you are looking for.